# COUNTIF using multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula here where in vba were the result should be something like this `get userid = myid where status = paid` (this is the logic of the code) But it doesn`t work.

```
UnclaimedOrder = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheet9.Range("B:B"), .Cells(SelRow, "A"), Sheet9.Range("P:P"), "Unclaimed")


SelRow = ID
.Range(P:P) = status
```

But the result are still zero.

Comment: can you post a representative sample of the data, what the value of .Cells(SelRow, "A") is, and what the expected answer is?  Otherwise, the best we can do it tell you that "the value of  .Cells(SelRow, "A") probably isn't what you think it is".

Comment: .Cells(SelRow, “A”) is equivalent to userid. sample That data has value of “1” and it will look same value in sheet9.Range(“B:B”) with status “Unclaimed” that can be look in sheet9.range(“P:P”)

Comment: if I use it as statement it should be like this “Count all Data where User ID(sheet9.range(“B:b”)) = MyID(.cells(selroe, “A”) and Status(sheet9.range(“p:p”)) = “Unclaimed”.